# how to display a widget only on a page where the custom field is defined?

Tags: custom-field, widgets

I have a set of local pages using a template, I want to display a widget only on pages where I have ticked the custom checkbox field.

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. What do you mean by "local pages"? What widget? What checkbox have you ticked and how is it stored? Additionally please share your research effort on this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom field (metadata) attached to a particular post, page or custom post type, you can do something like the following in your page template file:

Example `example-template-file.php`

```
<?php 

    $sidebar_id           = 'my-custom-sidebar-id';
    $my_custom_meta_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'my_custom_meta_key', true);

    if ( !empty($my_custom_meta_value) && is_active_sidebar($sidebar_id) ) {

        dynamic_sidebar($sidebar_id);

    }

?>
```

Notes: [dynamic_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar), [is_active_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_active_sidebar)